# How to round the decimal value to two places using JSTL where the List is created as output from database

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm working on small project where the the sql output (result set) is converted in to list and passed on to JSP to display the data.

How to I round a particular column contents to upto two decimal places.

Here's the code that I have so far:

Passing resultSet to create list:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
List<String> output = setData(rs);
```

Setting data:

```
public List<String> setData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

     ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
     int columns = md.getColumnCount();
     ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
     while (rs.next()){
         HashMap row = new HashMap(columns);
         for(int i=1; i<=columns; ++i) {           
             row.put(md.getColumnName(i),rs.getObject(i));
         }
         list.add(row);
     }
     return list;
 }
```

Using the above code in JSP page as shown below:

```
<%
 String sql = "My SQL code goes here";
 ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
 List<String> output = cf.getData(sql);
 pageContext.setAttribute("output",output);
%>
<tbody>
     <c:forEach items="${output}" var="ls">
         <tr>
             <td><c:out value="${ls.col1}"/></td>
             <td><c:out value="${ls.col2}"/></td>
             <td><c:out value="${ls.col3}"/></td>
             <td><c:out value="${ls.col4}"/></td>
             <td><c:out value="${ls.col5}"/></td>
         </tr>
     </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Now let's say "ls.col3" has decimal values (which unfortunately I can't restrict at SQL), how to restrict/round the decimals to two places?

Any insight is greatly appreciated :)

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was in my SQL code. I have used round function which doesn't seem to be working. I have replaced that with

> to_char(calculations, 'FM999D00')

to solve this issue.

Thanks a ton for looking into this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in jsp header

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

and this at lines where you need to display the value up to 2 decimals

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" value="${ls.col3}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. But where would I put the `C:OUT` in the above statement? Is it not required while using `fmt` ?

Comment: I don't think you will need  ' c:out ' tag, try replacing c:out tag with fmt tag as i posted.

Comment: Nope. That error'd out. `In &lt;formatNumber&gt;, value attribute can not be parsed into java.lang.Number: "{ls.col3}"`

Comment: Is your ls.col3 is a number in first place??

Comment: Yup. Other than Col1, everything else is a number. I did a `CAST((colx/coly) as REAL) AS COL3` in SQL. The sample output is 79.0000043

Comment: The error clearly says it,your ls.col3 is not a number,please check once again